# Remove the duplicate value in a string and output the total value

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object

I have a value something like this:

```
var x = "market^price^cost"; 

var y = "market^price"; //y could be anywhere in the x

var z = x + "+" + y //I want this to be `"market^price^cost"`



console.log(x + "+" + y) //"market^price^cost+market^price"
```

This logic should work only if `X` has the value of `y` if not the log value should be normal, we should get the entire string, the order of value of `y` could be different.

Comment: Are you saying that if the entire `y` string is contained anywhere within `x` then just output `x`, otherwise output `x` + `y`? Or...? What if there is an overlap like if `y = "cost^test"`?

Comment: It's tagged array, where is the array?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: @john see my answer

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

 
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
Array.prototype.uniqueMerge = function( a ) {
    for ( var nonDuplicates = [], i = 0, l = a.length; i<l; ++i ) {
        if ( this.indexOf( a[i] ) === -1 ) {
            nonDuplicates.push( a[i] );
        }
    }
    return this.concat( nonDuplicates )
};
function myFunction() {
var x = "market^price^cost"; 

var y = "market^price"; 
   
    var xS = x.split("^");
    var yS = y.split("^");
   var res = xS.uniqueMerge(yS).join("^");
    
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: let me know if there is something else you expected

Comment: how to do if x value has something like var x = "market^price^cost+dollar^pound";

Comment: sure thing, anytime! this issue in my context is very tricky. the code is mock one

Comment: ?? what's issue now ?

Comment: all the values are joining by "^" instead the value of y should join as "+"

Answer (score 0):

you can use lodash Array _.uniq() function

`return _.uniq((x+'^'+y).split('^')).join('^');`

or you can write a function to remove repeated data in Array;

```
function removeSame(arr) {
  for(let i = 0;i<arr.length;i++) {
   if(arr.indexOf(arr[i]) != i) {
      arr.splice(i,1);
      i--;  
   }
 }
 return arr;
}
return removeSame((x+'^'+y).split('^')).join('^')
```

Comment: @john https://jsfiddle.net/jxufbv66/1/  replace '+' with '^',you should use same split symbol。